# Calculate age from date of birth using django orm query

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I am calculating age using python code like

```
age = datetime.date.today().year - patient_table.dob.year - ((datetime.date.today().month, datetime.date.today().day) <
(patient_table.dob.month, patient_table.dob.day))
```

i return correct age. but i need this result using Django orm query how i can do this?

i tried like,

```
PatientTable.objects.filter(is_active=True,is_deleted=False).annotate(age=datetime.date.today().year - F('dob__year'))
```

but it getting wrong age.

Comment: I need age in years.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use RawSQL for this

```
from django.db.models.expressions import RawSQL

raw = 'Select DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), `yourappname_patienttable`.`dob`) from `yourappname_patienttable` u where u.`id`=`yourappname_patienttable`.id'

queryset = PatientTable.objects.all().annotate(age=RawSQL(raw, ()))

for obj in queryset:
    print(obj.age)
```

This will give you number of days since date of birth. Make sure to change `yourappname` in raw sql with your app name in which you have written your model.